# About a point in the the answer to "Riesz representation and vector-valued functions".

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, riesz-representation-theorem

In the Q&A [Riesz representation and vector-valued functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13473/riesz-representation-and-vector-valued-functions#), @anon gave an answer. why $m_{\phi}$ is well-defined?

Could some one give some reference or explain more about it?